# a code that checks the current url, checks if it contains a certain string

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

[Php condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hueg.png)

Could someone help me with a code that checks the current url, checks if it contains a certain string.

Ex: /myaccount/orders

and returns true

Comment: If you're using PHP8 (and you should be) see [str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) or [str_ends_with()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript you can try as below:
`window.location.pathname` will give the string added to the main url

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
if ((window.location.pathname ===  '/orders') {
      console.log("orders url");
 }

</script>
```

If php you can try this:

```php
    $URL = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    if (str_contains($URL, 'orders')) {
        print_r("URL contains orders");
    }
```

Comment: in wordpress elementor it only lets me play codes in php.

Comment: @MainartM updated the code for php. Try this

Comment: if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "quotes") !== false){
return true;
}